# Windows Update Client from WSUS Server - Manually

Tags: wsus

Is there any fast way to Windows update client from WSUS Server?

OS - Windows Server 2008 R2
Client - Windows XP & Windows 7
WSUS Server version 3.2.7600.226

Answer (score 3):

You can use wuauclt /detectnow command on Windows Client. 
Wait for some time and you can check the log at C:Windows\WindowsUpdate.log

Comment: If you have multiple clients you can psexec wuauclt /detectnow, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this script by Rob Dunn

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/82-windows-update-agent-force-script-email-results-version-2-6

it checks for updates on the wsus server, downloads and installs them, and you can set to reboot or not after the installation.

You can push it to the clients via psexec or your remote management solution.

Answer (score 0):

All the commands need to be run in a cmd window.

I used it lots of times in computers from Windows XP to Windows Server 2012 ;-)

**Force detection of updates (Light Level)**

`wuauclt /detectnow`

**Force detection of updates (Medium Level)**

```
net stop wuauserv
REG DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v LastWaitTimeout /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v DetectionStartTime /f
Reg Delete "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v NextDetectionTime /f
net start wuauserv
wuauclt /detectnow
```

**Force detection of updates (Do it bastard Level)**

```
net stop wuauserv

RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\Authcabs
RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\Datastore
RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\Download
RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\EventCache
RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\Selfupdate
RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\WebSetup
RD /S /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\WuRedir
Del /Q C:\windows\softwaredistribution\*.*

regsvr32 /s wuapi.dll
regsvr32 /s wups.dll
regsvr32 /s wuaueng.dll
regsvr32 /s wuaueng1.dll
regsvr32 /s wucltui.dll
regsvr32 /s wuweb.dll
regsvr32 /s MSXML3.dll

net start wuauserv
wuauclt /detectnow
```